# Google Chrome Page Open In Inspect Element Mode

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know weather it is possible to open a page always in inspect element mode thus I do not need to press F12 when page loads?

E.g. When a localhost page loads in chrome, I would like to launch it in inspect element mode.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If you detach the debugger from the window it will "follow" you as you navigate to different pages.

If you look at the top right of the debugger you'll see a window icon. Click and hold that and select the second option.

Comment: Link to the image, and then a user with privileges will embed it for you.